# How can I manage to change a field in my SQL DB, after i checked a value before?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

[image]

So. I Have this Table. I'm trying to update the value of the Availability filed from 0 to 1 after I checked that a code, for example 1234 exist in my DB.

Here is the code what I wrote:

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['kodi'])) {
try {
$sql = "SELECT codevalue FROM codes WHERE codevalue = ? AND availability = 0";
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(1, $_POST['kodi']);
$stmt->execute(); }
catch(PDOException $e) {
echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();}

if($stmt->rowCount() > 0){
header('Location: http://mysite/userpage');
$q = "UPDATE codes SET availability = '1' WHERE codevalue= ?";
$stmt->bindParam(1, $_POST['kodi']);
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($q);
$stmt->execute($q);} else {
echo "Code Not Exists"; }
```

The part with the $dbh variable:

```
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=x",$username,$password);
```

The HTML:

```
<form action ="thispage.php" method ="POST">
<input name="kodi" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Code" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
</form>
```

When I'm trying it, it redirects in my userpage but the field availability is still 0.

Comment: Are there any errors in your error log?

Comment: no. It just goes to the userpage, but when i check the phpmyadmin nothing has changed!

Comment: You reload phpmyadmin?

Comment: yep, reloaded a lot of times. but still nothing.

Comment: Please, just fetch the row and check it. Stop using rowCount. It isn't anymore efficient.  Whatever, you cannot start a new query until you clear the buffered results. So, close the statement. Also, put the whole code in a transaction?

Comment: Switch your `prepare` and `bind` statements in your second `if`.

Comment: @RyanVincent is right - `rowCount()` is not valid for `SELECT` statements in PDO. Good catch!

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, lets try it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(isset($_POST['kodi'])) {
$sql = "SELECT codevalue FROM codes WHERE codevalue = ? AND availability = 0";
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(1, $_POST['kodi']);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
if(!empty($result)) {
header('Location: http://mysite/userpage');
$q = "UPDATE codes SET availability = '1' WHERE codevalue= ? AND availability = 0";
$stmt->bindParam(1, $_POST['kodi']);
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($q);
$stmt->execute($q);
} else {
echo "Code Not Exists"; 
} 
}
```